# Why redux-persist doesn't persist my data?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-native, redux-persist

I'm making an application in React Native for Android using redux and redux-persist.
I want to store the ID of each user in my app with redux so they don't need to sign in again when they come back. I made a reducer called handleUser that allows users to sign in. It works perfectly without redux-persist, but when I use it, the store is not updated when my reducer is called. I don't know if it's the same on iOS.

I've already tried this: `$rm -rf node_modules && $npm install` and I also added `keyPrefix: ''` to my rootPersistConfig, I found this solutions on multiple askings, but it doesn't work. Note that I use react-navigation, even if I don't think it could be related to that.

Here is my configureStore:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import handleUser from './Reducers/userReducer'


import { persistCombineReducers } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'

const rootPersistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: storage,
    keyPrefix: ''
}

export default createStore(persistCombineReducers(rootPersistConfig, { handleUser } ))
```

Here is my reducer:

```
const initialState = { ID: '' }

function handleUser(state = initialState, action) {
    let nextState
    console.log(action) //I added this debugger but the behaviour is expected, no error.
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'SIGN_IN':
            nextState = {
                ...state,
                ID: action.value.ID
            }
            return nextState || state

        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default handleUser
```

And here is the component that allows to sign in:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Button } from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class SignIn extends React.Component {

    _signIn() {
        const action = { type: 'SIGN_IN', value: { ID: 'my_id' } }
        this.props.dispatch(action)
        console.log(this.props) //shows ID as undefined when using redux-persist
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
                <Button
                    title='Sign in'
                    onPress={ () => this._signIn() }
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    mainContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
})

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        ID: state.ID
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SignIn)
```

I expect that when I display `this.props` in my SignIn component, after calling the reducer, I find the value `my_id`. The problem is that it stays undefined. The console doesn't display any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed ! The ID was well stored, but I couldn't read it. Thank to Aluminium22 who gave me a better way to read the store. I created a new file called `GetStore.js` with a function that I use when I need my ID:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage'

export default function getStore(callback) {
    return AsyncStorage.getAllKeys((err, keys) => {
        return AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys, (error, stores) => {

            const store = stores[1]
            let parsedStore = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(store[1]).handleUser) //handleUser is my reducer

            callback(parsedStore)
        })
    })
}
```

So that when I want to read the store I do:

```
import GetStore from 'your GetStore.js file path'

//...

GetStore( store => {
    console.log(store)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I would check a few things.

- Log the persist store, to see if it's storing.
  type showAsyncStorageContentInDev() in your RND console.
  or log using:

```
AsyncStorage.getAllKeys((err, keys) => {
  AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys, (error, stores) => {
    stores.map((result, i, store) => {
      console.log('log async: ',{ [store[i][0]]: store[i][1] });
      return true;
    });
  });
});
```

clearly you will need to place the above code at a point in your code that it would have stored information.

- Ensure that you're using the PersistGate provided by redux-persist.

```
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'

// ... normal setup, create store and persistor, import components etc.

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <RootComponent />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

as described in the documentation.
https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

Comment: Where can I find the RND console (I searched but it's really confused) ? Regarding the PersistGate, I already use it.

Comment: React Native Debugger = RND (i think it may be mac only), that command won't execute in a typical remote debug session.

Comment: Ok, I am not on mac. Any other suggestion ? I logged persistor with a simple console.log() but I guess it's useless.

Comment: k, I updated my answer with another way to log async storage. I feel like your async is likely not storing.

Comment: Thank for the tip ! I imported AsyncStorage from `@react-native-community/async-storage` that I've installed. I logged the store after the dispatch in the function `_signIn()`. I see 2 stores displayed and both show `my_ID` as value of ID ! So my async stores the ID. I think I should read my store this way. I will try it and if it works, I will consider it fixed.

Comment: @Pasteque glad we could get it figured out. Good luck with your app!